# python sqlite3 unable to use conditions in query( >,<,=)

Tags: python

I am running into an odd problem,

setup is: Python 3.6.5 and sqlite3

I am running a simple query in DB, assume "`c`" is my cursor object:

```
c.execute("select count from mydb where bytes is ?",(myvariable,))
```

this works absolutely fine, but if i would add ">"  to it

```
c.execute("select count from mydb where bytes is > ?",(myvariable,))
```

i get the following error:

> OperationalError: near ">": syntax error

This is working absolutely fine in python 2.7,

I would appreciate any help over it.

Regards,

Harry

Comment: The SQL grammar for this use case is `"SELECT count FROM mydb WHERE bytes > ?"`. `is` in `"SELECT count FROM mydb WHERE bytes is ?"` is synonymous with `=`